# How to display different SVG icon in the same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg

I am working with a ponctual layer in QGIS 2.12.3 (Lyon). I have a determine a few points in my layer. Each point represents a different activity (ex : climbing, hiking, etc). In order to have a proper symbology, i have imported a few SVG icon.

At this time, i want each of my point to be represented by the corresponding activity. I am unable to do so. Could you help me figure it out?

[image: Layer symbology example]
Here is an example of what i am looking for

1. Each point with pointed with an arrow = Hiking
2. Each point with a star = Rock climbing
3. Each point = Kayaking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your few points contain an attribute describing its activity, you can use the **Categorized** or **Rule-based** style by going to:

*Right-clicking your layer > Properties > Style*

Then:

- Change *Single Symbol* to one of the suggested styles (**1**)
- Select the column containing your activity attributes (**2**)
- Click the *Classify* button (**3**)
- *Double-click* a symbol (**4**)
- Select *Simple marker* (**5**)
- Select *SVG marker* (**6**) and choose your icon:

[image: Categorized style]

Comment: I have 255 different attributes. Is there any quicker way to add svg's? Like adding the svg file location to each attribute? But how can I visualize then them after?

Comment: @TamasKosa - It may be possible with a script since 255 attributes is quite a lot! I would suggest [asking a new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as I'm not sure how to easily achieve this through the GUI =)

Comment: @TamasKosa - Most welcome, would be interesting to see a solution!

Comment: here is the question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188912/how-to-display-different-svg-icon-in-the-same-layer-in-qgis-based-on-attribute-v